# Problem publishing ethereum transaction after signing

Tags: web3j, sendtransaction

I am trying to publish ethereum raw transaction after signing, with proper gas fees, and chainID.
Unexpectedly, some signatures are published but some others fail to publish with error `Invalid Sender.` I am developing on Goerli testnet.

I do the signing with the same private key. Here are few signatures which are published:

```
Signature 1: 3045022100EF87F8636AF537EE0CC5E98BFCE3C326D43903EBCE9ED84AEC85048B5C3F3AE202207BEE6B1C2FD192499205B9D56B48134115BF15816053C030CD11524B55CB4BF3
Transaction Hash 1: 0x92097d82e0f400b5eb263f8cbf22283cf9ba67f39f302e15b3f8d748a0fc4797

Signature 2: 3045022100D21B1D77A747EAE770AA0034978DF1A50B07B9111E73DBE0E030BE83939A41080220390DB9C63FF95A3E519A280069E601E05FADA6E567F4E2D888758EF947491DDC
Transaction Hash 2: 0x70252700ee2ec6e04693bfdf1073ec7c607e671bdd73686423067d53cbd7e91d

Signature 3: 3045022100B4C1DF4DACB300D68675DD87DA855345AE09706D7E5AB58F892A17B1A177C02602201B3473C0499870662CFBF79D849D82C3E54741CD2B908BFFA0D783D8BB1A33E2 
Transaction Hash 3: 0xa5fbf852a8e41b81a683848771f5d0b5f04c6b5d14853a9e32e461d0e54ee197
```

and few failure samples:

```
Signature 1: 3046022100A19A88889F23F5BFC2322ABA2C5D99CF8D6EC6F790946E72838C06BAD9DA1CDA022100B49A58DBC920AFBB20DB4FE4ADB6C11130E608C231EF9BBEEBD3CEADDE96D2A4

Signature 2: 3046022100D219073F24ABD90531C7174373EA9A165C039F86CD1B6A94B4587BB99D6B2FAB022100E97895CE1ABCF423B15BACB5B8C7BD93092D7970CCA1496F007E4B657A172844
```

I know the reason for padding with 0x00 as described [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/12554/why-the-signature-is-always-65-13232-bytes-long/12556#12556), but noway to force the signature algorithm not to pad the result since the values for R and S are stochastic. Zeros are padded Whenever R or S are negative (i.e. higher than 0x7F).
Can anyone help to solve this? What is wrong with my signatures?

Comment: can you see some code?  have you checked if there is a nonce problem?

Comment: @MajdTL thank you for your attention. I'm quite sure about the raw transaction, since when I sign it again, it is published successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem arises when S is negative! this causes the sign algorithm to pad this big number which zeros to make is positive and as a result the length of signature grows.

Y can solve this by making S non-negative as described in [BIP-0062](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0062.mediawiki) by adding a big number to S when it is a negative number.

If S is negative, first byte of S in signature if 0x00.

```
BigInteger bigR = new BigInteger(r);
    BigInteger bigS;
    if (s[0] == (byte) 0x00) {
        byte[] s_new = Arrays.copyOfRange(s, 1, s_length);
        bigS = new BigInteger(s);
        if (checkHighS(bigS)) {
            bigS = (new BigInteger(HexUtils.hexStringToByteArray(sThreshold))).subtract(new BigInteger(s_new));
        }
    } else {
        bigS = new BigInteger(s);
    }

private static boolean checkHighS(BigInteger s) {
    return s.compareTo(new BigInteger(HexUtils.hexStringToByteArray(maxValueForS))) > 0;
}
```